# Stop Chrome from scrolling down every time I hit space

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, scrolling

In Google Chrome on Fedora 13, how do I keep it from scrolling down every time I hit space?

Comment: I have a feeling you won't have much luck with this one mate, it seems to be built in to most web browsers, and I haven't come across a way to change it. No harm in trying though I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [shortcut manager extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) and bind <kbd>Space</kbd> to a different action.

Comment: Not your fault, but that URL doesn't exactly scream out "shortcut manager" to me.

Comment: @Ignacio: That's not surprising, it's a hash of a randomly generated number (a public key). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882981/google-chrome-alphanumeric-hashes-to-identify-extensions

Comment: Very informative. I'm guessing that they probably want you to use some sort of search engine to find the extension you care about instead...

Comment: I guess that's the definitive proof that user-friendly URIs have nothing to do with SEO ;-)

Comment: Name is misleading, should be "shortcut key manager"